# How can I configure my wireless router to connect to the internet through another wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I wasn't very specific on my title, but I'll elaborate. For the purposes of my question, I'll call one router Bad Router and the other router Good Router (Which is true, btw). Here is the outline:

- Modem: Regular wired modem working as Bridge
- Bad Router: 2.4Ghz wireless router, routing connection from modem (DHCP, NAT)
- Good Router: Dual-band wireless router, doing nothing at the moment

I have the Good Router connect by Ethernet. I don't have physical access to the Bad Router (For ignorant non-parental fascistic reasons). However, I have wireless access to it (Including configuration).

I want to know if I can connect the Good Router to the Bad Router, and then configure the Bad Router to directly connect my Good Router to the modem so it can handle everything (Almost bypassing it, if you will). The Bad Router should preferably stay with its own DHCP. Even though I want to bridge the Modem through the Bad Router to my Good Router, when reading the Wireless Bridging methods that I found on Google (And here) this is not what seems to be described.

Scheme: [Modem] --Bridge--> [Bad Router] --Bridge--> [Good Router] --DHCP/NAT--> Connected devices

I'm asking the question in a generic way. Meaning that I'm not specifically limiting it to my routers  or firmware being used. I saw similar questions here and found other ways of doing what I asked in the title, but nothing specifically like this.

Thanks for your attention, hopefully you can help :).

Comment: This would leave other devices connected to the bad router without Internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. I was looking at the wrong way of doing it. It can be done if your firmware supports a "client mode" where it makes your second wireless router look like a regular device to the first. Then your second router will get the WAN from the first router, without even touching it. It can be easily done with dd-wrt, not limited. Next I'll try using my second band as an AP.

P.s.: If you got across this post and wants a mode detailed explanation with links to guides and firmwares, just comment on this answer and I'll do so.

Comment: Still got links to those guides? From what I have read, the good router then looses its wireless connectivity and must be accessed via its LAN ports. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to wanting to extend the range of Bad Router.

If your Good Router has a Repeater mode, you can connect it to Bad Router, then have your devices connect to Good Router. The Good Router I use right now, ASUS RT-AC68U has this Repeater mode:

[image: ASUS RT-AC68U repeater mode]

You'll be asked for the wireless password to Bad Router, then you can create your own WLAN.

This will let other devices continue to use Bad Router.